# Please tell me how called this UI name

Tags: ios, uitextfield, messenger

What is this UI name?
It's just like a sticking on the keyboard...
and like a messenger apps UITextField...
I don't know this UI name.
What is that?

[image]

Comment: "...like a sticking on the keyboard"? What are you talking about? You have a red circle on a screen-shot and it is not at all clear what you're asking about. You mention a keyboard, but there's no keyboard in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with input accessory view of `UIViewController`

Use Your text as input accessory view of `UIViewController`  so remove that bottom view from storyboard

Add Following in your view controller

```
var viewAcc: UIView?
var sendButton: UIButton!
var inputTextField: UITextField!

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return viewAcc
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

In View Did load method add following code  
Note:Please change constraints according to your requirement

```
    viewAcc = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    inputTextField = UITextField (frame: CGRect(x:8, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44 ))
    inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil
    inputTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
    inputTextField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
    viewAcc?.backgroundColor = .white
    viewAcc?.addSubview(inputTextField);

    let topBorderView = UIView()
    topBorderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: topBorderView)
    viewAcc?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(0.5)]", views: topBorderView)

    sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.isEnabled = true
    sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    viewAcc?.addSubview(sendButton)

    inputTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    viewAcc?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewAcc, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))
```

Goto Storyboard select your tableview and set keyboard dismiss mode to interactive that's it

Now you can drag to dismiss keyboard and textfield along with your finger

**EDIT IPHONE X SUPPORT**

```
lazy var viewAcc: SafeAreaInputAccessoryViewWrapperView = {
    return SafeAreaInputAccessoryViewWrapperView(for: button)
}()
```

Here is complete demo https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView

Hope it is helpful